# pthread_cancel() not working when passing in a type casted void pointer

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, void-pointers

I am working upon a project, which requires me to store all references to pthreads using void pointers, and to create and cancel these threads using wrapper functions.

I have therefore ended up with the following:

```
typedef void * ThreadHandle_t;

void * endlessWhileLoop(void * p){
    while(1);
} 

int createThread(ThreadHandle_t * handle){
    pthread_t thread;
    int ret = pthread_create(&(thread), NULL, endlessWhileLoop, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    /* Configure the ThreadHandle to point to the task */
    if (handle != NULL) {   /* If handle was passed in */
        *handle = &thread;
    }
    //ret = pthread_cancel(*(pthread_t *)*handle); <--This works

    return ret;

}

int deleteThread(ThreadHandle_t handle){
    int ret = pthread_cancel(*(pthread_t *)handle);

    if(ret != 0){
        printf("Failed to delete task, return code: %d", ret);
        return -1;
    }

    return ret;
}

int main( void ){
    ThreadHandle_t temp = 0;
    createThread(&temp);
    deleteThread(temp);
}
```

However, I receive a thread not found error from the cancel_thread call in deleteThread.

If I transfer the pthread_cancel call into the createThread function, it works, and the thread is cancelled, even when using the ThreadHandle.

Could it be that I am not passing the pthread_t using the ThreadHandle_t by reference correctly? I am quite confused...

Comment: Your logic really doesn't make any sense. Since `temp` is a pointer to void, you're going to have to use it to point to a `pthread_t`. But where do you allocate any `pthread_t` for it to point to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a big problem (from your `createThread` function):

```
pthread_t thread;
...
*handle = &thread;
```

Here you make `*handle` point to the *local* variable `thread`. But remember that `thread` will go out of scope when the function returns, and the pointer will no longer be valid. This will lead to *undefined behavior* when you later try to use this invalid pointer.

My recommendation is that you skip your `ThreadHandle_t` type, and simply return a `pthread_t` (not a pointer) from the `createThread` function, and pass it as it is to the functions that need it.

Comment: Ahh, of course! Thank you.  The createThread function cannot return a pthread unfortunately, as I am trying to make something that can be ported to another platform using these same functions.  I think the best way would be to typedef the ThreadHandle_t as a pthread, instead of a void pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Your pthread is a local variable in createThread. This is wrong. Make it global or define in main function.

After createThread returns, your handle points to nothing.